# Insertion into AVL tree only replaces root node

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I'm currently working on an assignment where the N most frequent words in a book (.txt) must be printed. The issue that I'm currently facing is that when I add a node to one of my trees, it simply replaces the root node and thus, the tree remains as a single node.

**Code snippet which adds words from the file "stopwords.txt" to a tree named stopwords:**

```
Dict stopwords = newDict();

if (!readFile("stopwords.txt"))
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open stopwords\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   FILE *fp = fopen("stopwords.txt", "r");

   while (fgets(buf, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL)
   {
      token = strtok(buf, "\n");
      DictInsert(stopwords, buf); //the root is replaced here
   }
   fclose(fp);
```

**The data structures are defined as follows:**

```
typedef struct _DictNode *Link;

typedef struct _DictNode
{
   WFreq data;
   Link left;
   Link right;
   int height;
} DictNode;

typedef struct _DictRep *Dict;

struct _DictRep
{
   Link root;
};

typedef struct _WFreq {
   char  *word;  // word buffer (dynamically allocated)
   int    freq;  // count of number of occurences
} WFreq;
```

**Code to insert and rebalance tree:**

```
// create new empty Dictionary
Dict newDict(void)
{
   Dict d = malloc(sizeof(*d));
   if (d == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory!\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   d->root = NULL;
   return d;
}

// insert new word into Dictionary
// return pointer to the (word,freq) pair for that word
WFreq *DictInsert(Dict d, char *w)
{
   d->root = doInsert(d->root, w); //the root is replaced here before doInsert runs
   return DictFind(d, w);
}

static int depth(Link n)
{
   if (n == NULL)
      return 0;
   int ldepth = depth(n->left);
   int rdepth = depth(n->right);
   return 1 + ((ldepth > rdepth) ? ldepth : rdepth);
}

static Link doInsert(Link n, char *w)
{
   if (n == NULL)
   {
      return newNode(w);
   }

   // insert recursively
   int cmp = strcmp(w, n->data.word);
   if (cmp < 0)
   {
      n->left = doInsert(n->left, w);
   }
   else if (cmp > 0)
   {
      n->right = doInsert(n->right, w);
   }
   else
   { // (cmp == 0)
      // if time is already in the tree,
      // we can return straight away
      return n;
   }

   // insertion done
   // correct the height of the current subtree
   n->height = 1 + max(height(n->left), height(n->right));

   // rebalance the tree
   int dL = depth(n->left);
   int dR = depth(n->right);

   if ((dL - dR) > 1)
   {
      dL = depth(n->left->left);
      dR = depth(n->left->right);
      if ((dL - dR) > 0)
      {
         n = rotateRight(n);
      }
      else
      {
         n->left = rotateLeft(n->left);
         n = rotateRight(n);
      }
   }
   else if ((dR - dL) > 1)
   {
      dL = depth(n->right->left);
      dR = depth(n->right->right);
      if ((dR - dL) > 0)
      {
         n = rotateLeft(n);
      }
      else
      {
         n->right = rotateRight(n->right);
         n = rotateLeft(n);
      }
   }

   return n;
}

static Link newNode(char *w)
{
   Link n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
   if (n == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory!\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   n->data.word = w;
   n->data.freq = 1;
   n->height = 1;
   n->left = NULL;
   n->right = NULL;
   return n;
}

// Rotates  the  given  subtree left and returns the root of the updated
// subtree.
static Link rotateLeft(Link n)
{
   if (n == NULL)
      return n;
   if (n->right == NULL)
      return n;
   Link rightNode = n->right;
   n->right = rightNode->left;
   rightNode->left = n;

   n->height = max(height(n->left), height(n->right)) + 1;
   rightNode->height = max(height(rightNode->right), n->height) + 1;

   return rightNode;
}

// Rotates the given subtree right and returns the root of  the  updated
// subtree.
static Link rotateRight(Link n)
{
   if (n == NULL)
      return n;
   if (n->left == NULL)
      return n;
   Link leftNode = n->left;
   n->left = leftNode->right;
   leftNode->right = n;

   n->height = max(height(n->left), height(n->right)) + 1;
   leftNode->height = max(height(leftNode->right), n->height) + 1;

   return leftNode;
}
```

I believe that most of the code is functional and it is simply the insertion which fails. When I attempted to debug this with gdb, I had discovered that the root node (d->root) was replaced before the recursive insert function (doInsert) was run, causing the program to always return the node n which, as a result, already exists in the tree. For example, if the text file contained the following:
a
b
c
then the program would first insert `"a"` as `stopwords->root`, then `"b"` would replace `"a"` and become the new `stopwords->root`, finally `"c"` would replace `"b"` as the `stopwords->root`, resulting in a tree with one node, `"c"`.

Comment: regarding; `typedef struct _DictRep *Dict;

struct _DictRep
{
   Link root;
};`  All this is completely unnecessary,  Rather just use: `DictNode *root = NULL:`

Answer (score 1):

There are many inconsistencies in your code.

One mistake is here:

```
d->root = doInsert(d->root, w);
```

You reassign unconditionally the root each time when you insert a new node.

You are supposed to return the new node from the function `doInsert` and to reassign the root only if the new node had become a new root.

But other mistake that you make is that you return from `doInsert` a local variable `n` that was not newly allocated but that was initialized to point to the previous root.

Inside `doInsert` you need to allocate a new node `NEW` and use a variable `x` to walk down from the root until you find a place to insert a new allocated node `NEW`.  If `x` stops at root then you reinitialize the `d->root = NEW`.

Answer (score -1):

Your function `newNode` just stores the passed string pointer, so what is pointed at will change when you modify the original string.

To prevent that, you should copy the input string on node insertions.

To archive that,

```
    n->data.word = w;
```

should be

```
    n->data.word = malloc(strlen(w) + 1);
    if (n->data.word == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(n->data.word, w);
```

Add `#include <string.h>` to use `strlen()` and `strcpy()` if it isn't.